# Add extra margin to the 960.gs framework without breaking it's purpose

Tags: css, frameworks, dry, 960.gs, separation-of-concerns

I have a design I want to accomplish and found 2 ways to achieve it using the 960gs framework. Although I don't know which one is better and there's not so much information about best practices in CSS as there is in, say, PHP. So I applied what I learned from vanilla HTML/CSS and PHP OO to find out none of them is actually "good".

This is [the important part of] my design:

[image: Web design]

The two ways of obtaining it based on the 960gs framework and the disadvantages I find are:

1. Modify the CSS to add margins to the text. Then, inside that div, apply a pure 960gs system with 12 columns. This works, but it makes the whole width wider than optimal (1000 px, not good for 1024x768, [9% of browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp)).
2. Use the 24 column model and leave the first and last column empty, so they become the margin. The problem with this is that then I'm using structure elements purely for visuals, plus having to write them in every single part of every page (not very DRY).

Example for the second:

```
<div class='grid_22 prefix_1'>    
  <p>
    The theory of relativity transformed theoretical <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics" title="Physics">physics</a> and <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomy" title="Astronomy">astronomy</a> during the 20th century. When first published, relativity superseded a 200-year-old <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics" title="Classical mechanics">theory of mechanics</a> created primarily by <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton" title="Isaac Newton">Isaac Newton</a>.
  </p>
</div>
```

What I want is to apply the 960gs framework in my page with some extra personalized margins.

**So, how would you avoid these problems I said for achieving what I want?**

PS, due to a bug in 960gs framework, it's not easy to find

Answer (score 0):

Your column is 960px wide and it seems fine. Both `box-shadow` and the left/right extra width of heading outside your column can be made without declaring a different width so it won't create an horizontal scrollbar.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/q8brv/ using absolute positioning for left and right part of decoration of the heading (compatibility IE8+. IE7- can live without box-shadow and this decorations imo ;) )

The upper limit with a resolution of 1024px is 1004px, though it's for maximized browser window.

Comment: The problem is not with the heading, the problem comes with the whole body of text, I want the text to have margins (the heading might be just temporary). Why do you say the upper limit is 1004px? Is that including the scrollbar?

Comment: I can't find margins but there are paddings: `<div class="grid_10 prefix_1 suffix_1">` will allow 1 column of "margin" on left and right with a 10-column wide text

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing now (2nd method), although `<div class="grid_10 prefix_1">` which is the same. The problem with that is that I'd have to write that in every section, and that doesn't look very... optimal. Nor if I want someone else in my project, then they'd need to learn about 960gs framework just to create a form for example.

Comment: You could add a custom class which CSS rule would be the concatenation of instructions applied to these 3 classes. `prefix_N` and `suffix_N` are one liner. Should be `.my_col { display: inline; float: left; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px padding-left: 80px; padding-right: 80px; }`. Or add this selector to the 3 rules where these 3 960gs classes appear.